# Error: No language undefined when using HumanizeDuration.js with angular-timer

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to get to get [angular-timer](https://github.com/siddii/angular-timer) working.  So far I'm not having much luck.

I'm getting an `Error: No language undefined.` error message in the console.  This refers to line 228 in [humanize-duration.js](https://github.com/siddii/angular-timer/blob/master/bower_components/humanize-duration/humanize-duration.js):

`throw new Error("No language " + dictionary + ".");`

I can't see anything wrong with what I'm doing.  I've included the files exactly as the [introduction page](http://siddii.github.io/angular-timer/index.html)

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately not any help, but I have the same problem.

Comment: I managed to get it working.  I found that my version of angular was different to what is used in `angular-timer`.  Try that, it might help.  I don't know what the issue with `HumanizeDuration.js` is though.

Answer (score 3):

Have you add the **language** attribute to the  tag?

```
<timer countdown="10" language="en" interval="1000" finish-callback="callbackTimer.finished()">{{minutes}}:{{seconds}}</timer>
```

There you can check which are supported: 
https://github.com/EvanHahn/HumanizeDuration.js#supported-languages